# how to use opengl with nvidia drivers?

Tags: c++, linux, opengl

I need to use OpenGL in my code. I am using CMake in order to search opengl in my system like this :

```
find_package(OpenGL REQUIRED)
```

It returns this error :

```
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:137 (message):
  Could NOT find OpenGL (missing: OPENGL_opengl_LIBRARY OPENGL_glx_LIBRARY
  OPENGL_INCLUDE_DIR)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:378 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  /usr/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindOpenGL.cmake:369 (FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS)
  CMakeLists.txt:8 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/kapil/Documents/OpenGLZero/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

I have installed nvidia-drivers-418 (not the headless ones). It shows all the opengl information here: 
[image: Opengl info in nvidia X Server]

Nvidia driver has `libnvidia-gl-418` package in it, and to me it seems it should provide me with the opengl capabilities. Here is the output of `dpkg -l libnvidia-gl-418`:

```
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name                               Version                Architecture           Description
+++-==================================-======================-======================-==========================================================================
ii  libnvidia-gl-418:amd64             418.56-0ubuntu0~gpu18. amd64                  NVIDIA OpenGL/GLX/EGL/GLES GLVND libraries and Vulkan ICD
ii  libnvidia-gl-418:i386              418.56-0ubuntu0~gpu18. i386                   NVIDIA OpenGL/GLX/EGL/GLES GLVND libraries and Vulkan ICD
```

and `dpkg -L libnvidia-gl-418`:

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libEGL_nvidia.so.418.56
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLESv1_CM_nvidia.so.418.56
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLESv2_nvidia.so.418.56
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLX_nvidia.so.418.56
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvidia-cbl.so.418.56
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvidia-eglcore.so.418.56
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvidia-glcore.so.418.56
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvidia-glsi.so.418.56
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvidia-glvkspirv.so.418.56
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvidia-rtcore.so.418.56
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvidia-tls.so.418.56
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvoptix.so.418.56
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/nvidia-418
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/nvidia-418/xorg
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/nvidia-418/xorg/libglxserver_nvidia.so.418.56
/usr/share
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/libnvidia-gl-418
/usr/share/doc/libnvidia-gl-418/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/libnvidia-gl-418/copyright
/usr/share/glvnd
/usr/share/glvnd/egl_vendor.d
/usr/share/glvnd/egl_vendor.d/10_nvidia.json
/usr/share/vulkan
/usr/share/vulkan/icd.d
/usr/share/vulkan/icd.d/nvidia_icd.json
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libEGL_nvidia.so.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLESv1_CM_nvidia.so.1
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLESv2_nvidia.so.2
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLX_nvidia.so.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvoptix.so.1
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/nvidia-418/xorg/libglxserver_nvidia.so
```

Last time, I had to install `mesa-utils` (for glxinfo) and `libgl1-mesa-dev` to use opengl. I want to know if nvidia drivers are of any use for opengl or I should have installed headless drivers instead? (How) Can I use opengl installed in nvidia? Thank you.

Comment: AFAIK the exact OpenGL library to use is selected by setting a symbolic link to it. I suppose there is such a symbolic link in the `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/` directory with the name similar to `libGL.so`.

Comment: I created the link : `lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root       10 Apr  9 12:17 libGL.so -> libGL.so.1`, but the include_dir is still not found. Error : `Could NOT find OpenGL (missing: OPENGL_INCLUDE_DIR)`. The library error has been removed though.

Comment: There was one link `libGL.so.1 -> libGL.so.1.0.0` present. Maybe the way I installed it doesn't create links. I haven't used the installer, rather the graphics-driver ppa and apt-get to install it.

Comment: Use the header files from `libgl1-mesa-dev` to compile your program as you did previously. The resulting program will still use the nvidia driver if it is installed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First and foremost: **Don't mess with any symlinks or libraries installed on your system by the package manager or the NVidia driver installer!** *If you did, you better return it to the state you found things.*

So what's missing are the OpenGL headers, *not the libraries*. Those use(d) to come with the NVidia driver installer, but if you use your systems package manager, they will be split into a different package.

Technically you could just copy the headers from the OpenGL registry into your project. But usually folks go with installing the default system package that ships the headers.

In case of Debian and Ubuntu that'd be the `mesa-common-dev` package. Never mind that it's the Mesa package, the headers are the same (functionally).